# Require in Nodejs and caching of modules

Tags: node.js, caching, process, operating-system, filesystems

I have a particular module named `pubsub` which is a class and needs to be initialized for any usage. I have a server process which during the starting up stage, requires `pubsub` module and calls init method on it. This application being a web based application, based on the actions the user does on the UI, particular modules are loaded dynamically and my question is if the newly loaded dynamic module also requires the same `pubsub` module, I see it doesn't need to be initialized. I guess that it is using the same `pubsub` module initialized during the start of the server process. How is this possible? (due to caching of modules in nodejs or some operating systems concept I am missing ?). Also, if I run another node process separately outside of server process which requires the same `pubsub` module, does it need to be initialized again? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Modules in Node are cached, requiring the same package returns the existing instance.
And of course if ti's a new process, it hasn't been loaded, and will init the first time it is loaded.